# When creating a model in Django why does the class inherit models.Model instead of just Model?

Tags: python

I am having trouble understanding inheritance in django models

If I create a model in django:

```
from django.db import models
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Can't I just I write

```
class Person(Model):
```

Since I already imported models and I am trying to inherit Model. Is Model a subclass of models? Also can I write the below, since I have imported models already.

```
    name = CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: Read about python modules. By the way it is not `Class` it is `class`.

Comment: `from django.db.models import Model,CharField,...etc` ... now you can just use `Model` if you want ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a Django question; it's a Python question.

If you're not familiar with the Python way of doing things, please read up on it before working in Django.

Investigate Python's module and import concepts to learn about this. A good place to start is the [Modules document in the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

The point is that `from django.db import models` imports the `models` module, so that you have a variable in that scope named `models` which is the models module.

It is possible to have something like `from django.db.models import Model, CharField`, but for Django models the convention is to import the `models` module, rather than its components.